# c++MPI instruction before all process started

Tags: c++, mpi

assuming i have code like this:

```
    int main(..){
            cout<<"something"<<endl;
            MPI_INIT(...);
            ..
            ..
            ..
            MPI_FINALIZE();
    }
```

I thought the cout before the init would be executed only once by the main process. Instead, it s executed as many times as the number of process. How can i run an instruction only one time and before that all process are started?

Comment: Put it in a script before calling `mpirun` maybe?

Comment: but i execute the mpirun in console .. so i have to write an other program ?!     Sorry but i m new with mpi

Comment: I mean you can write a little 3-line `bash` script (Linux/macOS) or a `BATCH` script (Windows) that does some setup and then calls `mpirun` afterwards.

Comment: ah ok, but i can't do in this way because it's not a cout but a function that returns a value. I wrote cout to simplify ..:(

Answer (score 1):

There is no portable way to achieve that !

Also, note that most MPI implementations start all the MPI tasks at the same time via `mpirun`. Long story short, `MPI_Init()` makes independent processes become a MPI task from a unique job.

with recent Open MPI, you can try to test the `PMIX_RANK` environment variable,
and i can only guess MPICH derivatives have a similar way to do the trick.

but once again, these are just non portable tricks, and you should not be doing that.

Comment: if i test rank and i execute an instruction only with one process, can i make the value returned by this instruction global ? ..

Comment: If I understand correctly, then yes, you can `MPI_Bcast()` that value.

Answer (score 1):

You are mistaking MPI for OpenMP. The latter uses the fork-join model where the program runs as a serial code initially and spawns threads to perform certain regions in parallel. MPI is a multi-process paradigm and typically all processes are started together and execute exactly the same code before `MPI_Init()`.

A relatively portable solution is to combine the ability of many MPI implementations to perform MPMD (multiple program multiple data) launches with a command line argument that results in that particular pre-initialisation code being executed:

```
int main (int argc, char **argv) {
   if (argc > 1 && argv[1] == "-preinit") {
      ...
      cout << "Something" << endl;
   }
   MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);
   ..
   ..
   MPI_Finalize();
}
```

(the `argv[1] == "-preinit"` is pseudo-code; you should use a string comparison function such as `strncmp` or a library that parses the command-line arguments such as `getopt`)

Then run it like:

```
mpiexec -n 1 ./program -preinit : -n 99 ./program
```

This will launch 100 MPI processes with only one of them receiving the `-preinit` command-line argument.

Still, the truly portable way is to first initialise MPI, then obtain the rank, and do whatever has to be done in rank 0.

Comment: thanks a lot. But variables in the if are not visible after the Mpi_init, am i right?

Comment: @dang92, all variables in MPI are local to the process and exist in the scope defined by the language syntax. In that regard, `MPI_Init` is just a regular function call, same as, e.g., `printf()`. If you need values from one process broadcasted to the others, use `MPI_Bcast`.