# Why is my MPI parallel program printing twice?

Tags: c++, performance, parallel-processing, mpi, hpc

My program is sorting array and works fine but I have only one small problem, it prints the unsorted array more then 1 time( depending on how much processes I have selected, if I select 2 it prints twice ). I just want to print the unsorted array only once. Is there a way of doing this? Thanks for your help :).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <mpi.h>

void merge(int*, int*, int, int, int);
void mergeSort(int*, int*, int, int);

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    /********** Create and populate the array **********/
    int n = atoi(argv[1]);
    int* original_array{ new int[n] {} };
    //int original_array[]=new int[n];

    int c;
    srand(time(NULL));
    printf("This is the unsorted array: ");
    for (c = 0; c < n; c++) {
        original_array[c] = rand() % n;
        printf("%d ", original_array[c]);
    }

    printf("\n");
    printf("\n");

    /********** Initialize MPI **********/
    int world_rank;
    int world_size;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);

    /********** Divide the array in equal-sized chunks **********/
    int size = n / world_size;

    /********** Send each subarray to each process **********/
    int* sub_array{ new int[size] {} };
    MPI_Scatter(original_array, size, MPI_INT, sub_array, size, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    /********** Perform the mergesort on each process **********/
    int* tmp_array{ new int[size] {} };
    mergeSort(sub_array, tmp_array, 0, (size - 1));

    /********** Gather the sorted subarrays into one **********/
    int* sorted = NULL;
    if (world_rank == 0) {
        sorted={ new int[n] {} } ;
    }


    MPI_Gather(sub_array, size, MPI_INT, sorted, size, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    
    /********** Povik na posledniot mergeSort call **********/
    if (world_rank == 0) {

        printf("Array state before final mergeSort call: ");
        for (c = 0; c < n; c++) {
            printf("%d ", sorted[c]);
        }
        
        printf("\n");

        int* other_array{ new int[n] {} };
        mergeSort(sorted, other_array, 0, (n - 1));

        /********** Pecati sortirana niza **********/
        printf("This is the sorted array: ");
        for (c = 0; c < n; c++) {
            printf("%d ", sorted[c]);
        }

        printf("\n");
        printf("\n");

        /********** Oslobodi memorija **********/
        delete[] sorted;
        delete[] other_array;

    }

    /********** Oslobodi memorija **********/
    delete[] original_array;
    delete[] sub_array;
    delete[] tmp_array;

    /********** Finalize MPI **********/
    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Finalize();

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move this:

```
   printf("This is the unsorted array: ");
    for (c = 0; c < n; c++) {

        original_array[c] = rand() % n;
        printf("%d ", original_array[c]);

    }
```

below the

```
int world_rank;
int world_size;

MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_rank);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);
```

and make only one process to print it, for instance, using rank = 0.

For instance:

```
  if(rank == 0){
    printf("This is the unsorted array: ");
    for (c = 0; c < n; c++) {

        original_array[c] = rand() % n;
        printf("%d ", original_array[c]);

    }
 }
```

What is happen is that your MPI implementation is spawning as many instance of that code as the number of processes that you have specified **right from the beginning of that code** and not from the `MPI_Init` call onwards. You can read in more detail explanation about [this here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47495108/cmpi-instruction-before-all-process-started).

> MPI is a multi-process paradigm and typically all processes are
> started together and execute exactly the same code before MPI_Init().

With this in mind you might have to adapt the rest of code accordingly. That last `MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);` looks redundant.